# How do you migrate a site page from 2010 to 2013?

Tags: 2013, error, page-layout, migration, pages

I'm migrating an entire site from SP2010 to SP2013, but naturally the Site Pages are going to be broken because the page layouts are invalid.  I tried detaching the page from the layout in designer but I get a strange error that says only "0x80070057".  Tried changing Page Settings through Content and Structure but that threw errors as well.  Has anybody had success in changing page layouts or otherwise migrating site pages to 2013?

Comment: Have you find the solution for the question, If yes please give me solutions as answer. I have the same requirement